# How to approach building an expression/condition evaluator GUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parsing

I have a winforms application that is connected to a database which contains a huge amount of measurement data of different datapoints. The data gets updated every few seconds, old values go to an archive table etc. I'm using EF6 for data access.

Now I need to build a GUI that offers some functionality as follows:

The user should be able to define conditions and/or expressions at runtime that then trigger some actions when true. An example in pseudo-code:

```
if ([Value of Datapoint 203] >= 45 and (TimeStamp of Datapoint 203 < "07:00am")
and (([Value of Datapoint 525] == 1]) or ([Value of Datapoint 22] < 0)])
then set [Value of Datapoint 1234] to ([Value of 203]/4) //or call a method alternatively
```

or an even simpler example in natural language (differs from the above):

```
if it is cold and raining, turn on machine XY
```

where *cold* and *raining* are values of certain datapoints and `turn on machine` is a method with a given parameter *XY*.

These expressions need to be saved and then evaluated in regular intervals of some minutes or hours. I did not face such a requirement before and I hardly know where to start. What would be the best practice? Is there maybe some sample code you know of? Or are there even controls or libraries for this?

***Update: Breaking it down to something more specific:***

Suppose I have a class like this:

```
class Datapoint
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

During runtime I have two objects of this type, `DatapointA` and `DatapointB`. I want to enter the following into a textbox and then click a button:

```
DatapointA.Value>5 && ( DatapointB.Value==2 || DatapointB.Value==7 )
```

Depending on the actual values of these objects, I want to evaluate this expression string and get a ***true*** or ***false***. Is this possible?

Comment: seems like what you already have with SQL ... no? If you really want to parse/evaluate/... such then the question is way to broad (you can basically read books on this single question: http://www.amazon.com/Compilers-Principles-Techniques-Tools-Edition/dp/0321486811))

Comment: Thanks. but I don't think the question is too vague: I do have objects with Id, TimeStamp and Value properties that I can read and write. I want to set one property depending on the values and timestamps of other objects based on the rules given in the expression. The expression must not be hardcoded but editable at runtime.

Comment: it's not to vague - it's to broad IMO - we cannot answer this in a few sentences or even a few pages ...

Comment: You might consider using the built-in compiler `CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("C#")`. Then you would wrap the statement in a method that returns a boolean. The class would implement a predefined interface that would accept your Datapoint objects as input.